# Laravel 5.2 ajax file upload does not receives file

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 application, where  i try to upload some files trough ajax, but the laravel does not receives them.

Here is my code:

```
function uploadImages(selector){
var file_data = selector.prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/uploadfile/', 
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(php_script_response){
        console.log(php_script_response);
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

Here is the php part:

```
public function uploadPhoto(Request $request){
    $string = str_random(40);
    $response = [];

    $file = $request->file('file');

    $response['str'] = $file;

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

The problem is, that $file is `NULL`. (the success function prints `Object { str: "NULL" }` to console).

I checked the headers sent in the Network tab of the console, and it seems the image is sent as expedted.
Does anybody have any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' id='choosePhoto' name='file'>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you set your `'files'=>true` in the form? Please post the form markup too

Comment: Where should I set this?

Comment: Please show me your form code.

Comment: I have updated the question with it. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use this jquery plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Add this on your js:

```
    $('#my-form').ajaxForm({

            beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options){
                // just like jquery ajax
            },

            success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){

                console.log(responseText);

            },

            clearForm: true //clear form after submit
        });
```

Then on your view:

```
<form id="my-form" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('my/route') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
    <input class="subir" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this time I cannnot use this plugin as I need to upload the images before the user finishes filling up the form.

Comment: Well, you could create 2 forms like look one. The first one could be the image form and the other one, the data form. Then you can catch with `keyup()` when the user is writing on the other form and submit the image. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the above code what i understood is problem you are having is not with the laravel uploader but with the jquery snippet.
In jquery you have to handle file uploads in a different way.
please find the [tutorial on creating a snippet to upload files via ajax/jquery here](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Also i would recommend changing the name from file to image or something

Comment: The javascript you sent does exactly the same thing I did: uses the FormData to process the files. Why the variable name  $file should be changed?